# Rating bar inflated crashing my app

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, ratingbar

When user set one item with "Consumido", he needs to set one rating to this item. I inflate the view with one rating bar, and when user clicks OK button, i try this.

```
builder.setNeutralButton(labelEditar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais().get(position).isConsumido()){
                        regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais().get(position).setConsumido(false);
                    }
                    else{
                        regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais().get(position).setConsumido(true);
                        AlertDialog.Builder avaliacaoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TelaCadastrados.this);
                        avaliacaoDialog.setTitle("Avalie este item!");
                        avaliacaoDialog.setView(R.layout.layout_alert_dialog_avaliacao);

                        avaliacaoDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais().get(position).setAvaliacao(reAvalia.getRating());
                            }
                        });
                        avaliacaoDialog.show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(TelaCadastrados.this, "Status de consumido alterado para: " + labelToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

On "Ok" click, the app crashes. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please share the error you are getting.

Comment: its a runtime error, "Unfortunately, seen.me has stopped."

Comment: See the log window/log panel. There is the reason why and where your app  is being crashed.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.widget.RatingBar.getRating()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please share some more code. You might just not hold a reference to the RatingBar...

Comment: final RatingBar reAvalia;
        reAvalia = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.reAvalia);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the view for your dialog but you are calling `reAvalia.getRating()` without ever setting `reAvalia` to anything. That's why you're getting a NullPointerExeption.

Comment: On onCreate i do this 
final RatingBar reAvalia;
        reAvalia = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.reAvalia);

Comment: But you haven't inflated the view yet. It doesn't get inflated until you set it as the view for the dialog. So it doesn't find it and sets it to null.

Comment: CaseyB, you could tell me how to do this?

Comment: You can create your own dialog subclass and you can control everything that happens in there.